# Can this portable power generator charge this battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am considering purchasing an e-bike but I have no outlets at my parking space and it's a non-removable battery. The e-bike looks like a motorcycle.

I am considering getting one of those portable power generators so I can recharge it at home and bring it down to charge the bike overnight.

I am completely ignorant when it comes to electricity. I just googled for a couple of hours trying to understand the different things (Amps, Volts, Watts, Watt-hour).

The bike specs are:

```
Motor:   500W
Battery: 72V/20Ah GEL SLA
Charger: AC100-120V, Smart Charger (Battery maintained while charging)
```

The battery I am looking at is titled: `AIMTOM Portable Solar Generator, 42000mAh 155Wh Power Station, Emergency Backup Power Supply W/ Flashlights, for Camping, Home, CPAP, Travel, Outdoor (110V/ 100W AC Outlet, 3x 12V DC, 3x USB Output)`

This is where I get confused. Looking at the 42Ah it looks like this could fully charge the bike twice.

Since I am not sure what I am doing, I also am looking at the 155Wh. From what google told me, the bike battery would be 1440Wh.
So this power generator would not even tickle the battery.

I am not sure what to think here. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Questions about the usage of a consumer products are off topic here.  Realistically, if you are going to ride a light electric motorcycle, pick one that is a) legal to operate where you intend and b) has a removable battery or folds to a size where you can keep it indoors.  Or just pedal, like humans have been doing for the past 150 years.

Answer (score 1):

Your bike has a 72V 20Ah battery which is 1440Wh.  The portable battery is 155Wh, so it will not charge the bike battery from flat to fully charged.  It depends how much you need to charge it after each use.

Based on the 155Wh and 42Ah, the portable battery must be 3.6v internally.

Comment: That's what I thought.
I would need a battery with more Wh?

Comment: Just for a rough estimate the bike battery specs put the weight around 7kg/15.5lbs so at the minimum you'd be looking for a portable charger around that weight if using the same battery tech (lead acid) and the same voltage (72V). Just for reference, the charger you were thinking about is only 1/3 the weight (2kg/4.5lbs) and charged to a much lower voltage

Comment: How did you do this weight math?

Comment: Instead of using a battery to charge a battery, you'd be better off having two bike batteries and swapping them out.